# boost::beast vs uwebsockets library performance c++

Tags: c++, boost-beast, uwebsockets, boost-beast-websocket

I'm porting a python application over to C++. As I'm not incredibly familiar with C++ I was wondering if there are any benchmark test result out there for websocket latency between the two libraries boost::beast and uwebsockets. As I have to start from scratch anyways, I do not have a preference.

The main aim to port to C++ is to deminish latency. Essentially, the program will recieve data through websocketstream, handle data, send out http request. What i could grasp from various online sources is that uwebsockets might have lower latency, but it can't send http request. I would need another library for that. With boost::beast i could do both.

In the end, the only thing i care about is the lowest amount of latency. So would uwebsockets + another library for http request be more efficient than boost::beast?

I get that it's a general question and relatively hard to answer. But maybe some of you have already benchmarked it for a similar goal with a similar program.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/tree/master/benchmarks